# PHP + Stripe API - set php object values dynamically from dot syntax

Tags: php, laravel, object, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe's (relatively) new Connect Account feature. Stripe returns a list of "fields_needed" for validation, and I update the Account object based on those fields. Here is a very basic solution :

```
public function setStripeValue($field, $value, $account){
switch ($field) {
  case 'legal_entity.additional_owners.address.city':
      $account->legal_entity->additional_owners->address->city = $value;
      return $account;
    break;

  case 'legal_entity.additional_owners.address.country':
      $account->legal_entity->additional_owners->address->country = $value;
      return $account;
    break;

  case 'legal_entity.additional_owners.address.line1':
      $account->legal_entity->additional_owners->address->line1 = $value;
      return $account;
    break;

  case 'legal_entity.additional_owners.address.line2':
      $account->legal_entity->additional_owners->address->line2 = $value;
      return $account;
    break;

  // etc etc ... 50 fields or more!
```

As you can see, the request is always in the format `legal_entity.additional_owners.address.city` or similar (can be 1 level or many levels deep) and the value definition is always in the format `$account->legal_entity->additional_owners->address->city` or similar.

Is there a better way to set these values recursively than a switch statement? There can be one or many fields to be set (I call this function multiple times) and the fields can be nested to any length. Thanks!

**tried so far:**

```
    function get($path, $object, $value) {
        $temp = &$object;
        foreach($path as $var) {
            $temp =& $temp->$var;
        }
        $temp = $value;
    }

    $key = explode(".", $field);
    get($key, $account, $value);
```

This seems to update the values within the object but doesn't play well with Stripes API, which must update using PHP object system (`->`) and then `$account->save();`

Comment: explode you `$field` and then do a array reduce to access the `$account` with each value of the splitter array.

Comment: @marciojc could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @marciojc, not sure you can use array_reduce here, he needs a recursive function that gets to the last item of each array to set a value... I'm trying to write one down but I'm quite stuck

Comment: @Leon, have you tried writing some code?

Comment: I think you should change the way you put data in $field from the origin... This seems not to be a good implementation of whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @Alberto . The dot syntax field names are set by stripe, and cannot be changed. My previous attempts (over the last 48 hours!) were along the lines of - explode the fields string - loop over each section of the exploded string - $temp =& $temp->$var; adds the string to an object. I'll update my question, but to be honest it didn't work!

Comment: Wait, I think I found one

Comment: @Leon `$temp->{$var}`

Comment: The get function works if you change ->$var with $temp[$var] and return $temp (without then setting $value as value) but you only get the value of the last element of each array... You need to set it. Are you using the Stripe PHP API (https://stripe.com/docs/api/php) ?

Comment: Check the duplicate question, you'll find the answer there.

Comment: Results in "Indirect modification of overloaded element of Stripe\StripeObject has no effect" but we are getting closer! Thanks I'll check the duplicate

Comment: I'd seen that duplicate. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in this context.